# Why is `E_USER_DEPRECATED` excluded by `bootstrap.php.cache`?

Tags: php, symfony

I notice that my `bootstrap.php.cache` file begins with this:

```
namespace {
    error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/./autoload.php';
}
```

Why is Symfony overriding my preferred `error_reporting` settings? There seems to be no way to change this, as it is hard-coded into `Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they want to be able to raise `E_USER_DEPRECATED` by [**`trigger_error()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

If Symfony accepted the symfony-developers `error_reporting()` settings, then Symfony couldnt raise its own internal "*xxx is depecated*" warnings properly.

Comment: Of course! I think you mean `E_USER_DEPRECATED`, though.